# Hudson and gitosis

Tags: git, hudson, gitosis

I'm trying to get Gitosis and Hudson to play nice together.  I am able to pull from the repository without password access by editing ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and putting my public key in that file.  However, whenever I attempt to run my Hudson project I immediately get the error listed below.  Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

PS This works fine from command line

Sorry if these questions seems basic, I'm coming from a GitHub background and have never used gitosis before

```
Started by user anonymous
Checkout:workspace / C:\Documents and Settings\hudson\.hudson\jobs\<job>\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@13b8b4d
Using strategy: Default
Checkout:workspace / C:\Documents and Settings\hudson\.hudson\jobs\<job>\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@13b8b4d
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
ERROR: Failed to clean the workspace
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete C:\Documents and Settings\hudson\.hudson\jobs\<job>\workspace
at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:263)
at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:305)
at hudson.FilePath$9.invoke(FilePath.java:826)
at hudson.FilePath$9.invoke(FilePath.java:824)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:758)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)
at hudson.FilePath.deleteRecursive(FilePath.java:824)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:208)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:835)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:782)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:758)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.gerRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:782)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:568)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1217)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:508)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:424)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1367)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Failed to delete workspace
ERROR: Cause: Unable to delete C:\Documents and Settings\hudson\.hudson\jobs\<job>\workspace
Trying next repository
ERROR: Could not clone repository
FATAL: Could not clone
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:850)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:782)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:758)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.gerRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:782)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:568)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1217)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:508)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:424)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1367)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like [Pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to keep your key loaded.  You will still need to enter your passphrase, but only once.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use Pageant to do this?  I'm unfamiliar with that program.

Comment: [Here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter9.html) is the official page.  Basically you load your key into pageant and it will keep it loaded so you don't need to enter your passphrase every time.  Depending on how you are accessing the repo, you may also need to create an environment var called `GIT_SSH` and point it to a program called [plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out.  It turns out it was just another process holding onto the directory.  When I restarted the machine, it works fine now.